# Why does WebDriver not move to the next page when "clicking" an element?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am doing:

```
driver = new webdriver.Builder()
          .forBrowser('safari')
          .build();
var referrer = 'http://localhost:3000/tours/hood-river';
//        console.log(referrer);
        driver.get(referrer);
        driver.findElement(By.id('requestGroupRate')).click();
        //requestGroupRate is a link, so clicking it should move it to a new page

        driver.wait(function(){

                return driver.findElement(By.id('myThing')).then(function(element){
                console.log("hereere");
                assert(element.value === referrer);
                done();
            });
        },10000);
```

I find that the `findElement(By.id('myThing'))`, fails, even though the page it should be on clearly has 'myThing'. But if I change the line to

```
driver.findElement(By.id('requestGroupRate'))..
```

Then the element is found! This leads me to believe, that the click() does not cause the driver to navigate to the link.

EDIT: The link I am trying to click on:

```
<a id="requestGroupRate" 
   href="/tours/request-group-rate">Request Group Rate.</a>
```

Comment: Are you sure `By.id('requestGroupRate')` is the locator of the clickable element? Maybe it is of a wrapper.

Comment: @acdcjunior I added the link to my question description...

Comment: the link has href attribute, so it's no doute the link is clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply add driver.sleep(10000) after click() for debug purpose.

if the page changed, means the link and click() worked and the possible failed reason it's when script click on the link, the page is still loading, so browser failed to response to the click event.

then you can move the driver.sleep(10000) after browser.get() to see click() can work or not.

Comment: Please, please don't use sleeps... use `WebDriverWait` instead. See google for lots more info.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [acdcjunior](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850609/acdcjunior) findout if element is clickable use browser developer tools. Chrome it is a side panel, Firefox it is a marker at the end of the HTML tag.

I have had issues getting Selenium to click on a GIS map. In that case i use an alternative (will need to translate this Java into Javascript):

```
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('map_container').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));");
```

Also suggest testing your xpath in the browser developer console:

```
    document.evaluate(".//tagName[@id='Query']", document,null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
```

Or testing your cssSelector in the browser developer console:

```
    document.querySelector('#idtext')
```